# Consider an entire function $f$. What can be said about $\inf_{z\in\mathbb{C}}|f(z)|$?

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, supremum-and-infimum, entire-functions

> Consider an entire function $f$. What can be said about $\inf_{z\in\mathbb{C}}|f(z)|$?

**My attempt:**

Consider $B:=\overline{B}(0,r)$ with $r>0$. Then $$ \inf_{z\in\mathbb{C}}|f(z)|\le \inf_{z\in B}|f(z)|\overset{\mathrm{Weierstrass}}{=}\min_{z\in B}|f(z)| =\min_{z\in\partial B}|f(z)|.$$

If $f=C$ constant, then $\inf_{z\in\mathbb{C}}|f(z)|\le C$. Otherwise, $f$ is a nonconstant entire function, implying it is unbounded, i.e. there is no $K\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\inf_{z\in\mathbb{C}}|f(z)|\le |f(z)|\le K$. Therefore $\inf_{z\in\mathbb{C}}|f(z)|=-\infty$. Or should I say that it doesn't exist?

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: $|f(z)|\geq 0$, so it can't be true that $\inf_{z\in \mathbb{C}} |f(z)|=-\infty$. So instead, the question, given your deductions so far, is: If $f\not \equiv C,$ does it then necessarily follow that $\inf_{z\in\mathbb{C}}|f(z)|=0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f$ is constant and it always takes the value $\omega$, then $\inf_{z\in\mathbb C}\bigl\lvert f(z)\bigr\rvert=\lvert\omega\rvert$.

Otherwise, since $f(\mathbb C)$ is dense, $\inf_{z\in\mathbb C}\bigl\lvert f(z)\bigr\rvert=0$.

Comment: I have a question about the last implication. As you said, $f(\mathbb{C})$ is dense, thus in particular there is some $z_0$ such that $f(z_0)\in B(0,\varepsilon)$. So, $0\le |f(z_0)| \le \varepsilon$. Therefore $\inf|f(z)|\ge 0$, but by taking the limit $\varepsilon\to 0$ we also find the other inequality. In conclusion, $\inf_{z\in\mathbb{C}}|f(z)|=0$?

Comment: Yes, that would be correct.